# Adding additional services to IServiceCollection in Startup class for Integration test in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to add a few more Services in IServiceCollection Object from my Integration test project to the Startup.cs.
I am adding my TestConfiguration in the ConfigureServices method of the WebHostBuilder of my integration test, but its called before my startup class so my test configuration gets overridden.

**Test class TestSetup.cs**

```
 var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseEnvironment("development")
                .UseContentRoot(contentRoot)
                  .ConfigureServices(TestConfigureServices)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();



 private void TestConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton((c) =>
                new TokenClient(TokenEndpoint,
                                "api.public.client",
                                "psdfsrfsdf",
                                innerHttpMessageHandler: _handler));
        }
```

**API Project Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
services.AddSingleton((b) =>
                new TokenClient(m.AccessTokenUrl,
                                SecurityConfig.PublicApiClientId,
                                SecurityConfig.PublicApiClientPassword));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create different `Startup` classes for Production and Tests.
Then the necessary `Startup` will "choosen" depending on the current build.
Example:

```
public class Startup  
{    
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {    
    services.AddTransient<IYourService, YourService>();
  }
}

public class StartupTesting  
{    
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {   
    services.AddTransient<IYourService, YourMockedService>();
  }
}


var assemblyName = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName;
//var assemblyName = typeof(StartupTesting).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName;

var host = new WebHostBuilder()  
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseStartup(assemblyName)
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**Updated:**

There are second approach - using environment specific methods in one Startup class. But my humble opinion is that this causes too much coupling between the tests and the staging code.

[Example you can see here](https://andrewlock.net/configuring-environment-specific-services-in-asp-net-core-part-2/#environmentspecificmethodconventions)

Answer (score 0):

Since ASP Core 2.1 there is a `ConfigureTestServices` method available on `WebHostBuilder` that runs after registrations from `Startup.cs`. So your code would look like this:

```
 var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("development")
            .UseContentRoot(contentRoot)
              .ConfigureTestServices(TestConfigureServices)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```